# How to select the id from the highest table within the hierarchy which is not null - stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field called eligible(bool), within 3 tables. The tables are Boss, managers, workers. Hierarchy goes Boss - Managers - workers. A worker might NOT have a manager, a manager might NOT have a boss. They all have this eligible field though. I a boss has the eligible field set to true, all his managers and all the workers of his managers will inherit this property too.

Lets say I have a job id which is always assigned to a worker. First I need to find out if he has a manager and a boss and after get the eligible field from the highest within the hierarchy.

So the worker has a manager and the manager has a boss, it should get the boss's eligible field. If the worker has a manager, but the manager has no boss assigned to him, it should get the manager's eligible field. If the worker has no manager(meaning he cannot have a boss assigned to him), it should get the worker's eligible field.

I am kind of stuck with this.. I have tried `SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN B.Id is not null) THEN RETURN..` and a few other variations, but no luck yet. Any help?

```
SELECT W.Id, M.Id, B.Id
-- CAST(case when ED.Id is not null) THEN return M.Eligible 
from Job J 
Inner Join Worker W on W.Job_Id = J.Id
Left Join Manager M on M.Id= W.ManagerID
Left Join Boss B on B.Id = M.BossId
Where J.Id = 1 and B.Id is not null and M.Id is not null
```

So far I can only get the ids, but do not know how to return just the eligible `Boolean` field of the highest ranking worker

Example data -

Jobs Table
----------
Id 1, Worker 1, 
Id 2, Worker 2,
Id 3, Worker 3,

Workers Table
-------------
Id 1, ManagerId 1, eligible false
Id 2, ManagerId 2, eligible false
Id 3, ManagerId null, eligible true

Managers Table
--------------
Id 1, BossId 1, eligible false
Id 2, BossId null, eligible true

Boss Table
----------
Id 1, eligible true

The reason why I use `LEFT JOIN` because with `INNER JOIN` it would only return values if it has a boss too.

Job 1 would be true because it goes all the way up to the boss `Table` which is set to true

Job 2 would be true because it goes up to the manager level and it is set to true

Job 3 would be true because it is set to true for the worker and as it has no boss nor manager, it would take that value

EDITED SQL STATEMENT

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (B.Id IS NULL) then CASE WHEN (M.Id IS NULL) then W.Id else B.Id END
from Job J 
Inner Join Worker W on W.Job_Id = J.Id
Left Join Manager M on M.Id= W.ManagerID
Left Join Boss B on B.Id = M.BossId
Where J.Id = 1 and B.Id is not null and M.Id is not null
```

Obviously the `SELECT` line is not working. Any idea how to do a `CASE WHEN` in this case?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN's when you require NOT NULL results for those tables?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You should be able to do this with the `COALESCE` function, which returns the first non-null value from a list. You also need to omit the requirements that `B.Id` and `M.Id` are not null, since that essentially converts your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    -- Returns first non-null value, so order by hierarchy
    COALESCE(B.Eligible, M.Eligible, W.Eligible) AS Eligible
from Job J 
    Inner Join Worker W on W.Job_Id = J.Id
    Left Join Manager M on M.Id= W.ManagerID
    Left Join Boss B on B.Id = M.BossId
Where J.Id = 1
```

Comment: Nice, Thank you. I have just managed to do it with multiple `CASE WHEN` statement as `CASE WHEN (B.Id IS NULL) And (M.Id IS NULL) THEN W.Eligible
 WHEN (B.Id IS NULL) THEN M.Eligible
 ELSE B.Eligible`  but you solution is much better

Answer (score 0):

I'd give a shot to something like this

```
select max(ifnull(w.Eligible, false) or ifnull(m.Eligible, false) or ifnull(b.Eligible, false)) as grand_elegible
from Job J 
Inner join Worker W on W.Job_Id = J.Id
left join Manager M on M.WorkerId = W.Id
left join Boss B on B.Id = M.BossId
where J.Id = 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this syntax will work with SQL-Server. To be fair, OP did have MYSQL tagged at first.

Comment: thx for justifying me, :)   not sure about MS SQL - probably needs nvl() instead of ifnull(), but general idea should be the same

Comment: I believe it's `ISNULL()`. Also, I don't believe the `MAX()` function supports multiple arguments.

Comment: it's one argument : expression with two OR

Answer (score 0):

Tamas,

As said above, hard to know which SQL to follow given the tags - so I'm using MySQL's IFNULL for the example.  Also - a minor question about the field names at the bottom.  That said, this should do it:

```
SELECT IFNULL( B.Eligible, IFNULL( M.Eligible, W.Eligible ) )
from Job J 
Inner Join Worker W on W.Job_Id = J.Id
Left Join Manager M on M.WorkerId = W.Id
Left Join Boss B on B.Id = M.BossId
Where J.Id = <JobID>
```

The main change is in the select field.  The question for fields: is it really M.WorkerID?  Seems that would be where you would check M.Id to W.ManagerId (or some such)
finally - I left `<JobID>` in there as a placeholder for a parameter (assuming the 1 was for testing purposes)

Hope that helps,
John

Comment: Sorry, I the `LEFT JOIN`s mixed up and corrected it